# imagettftext() - Cannot find font location

Tags: php, captcha, imagettftext

I am using the imagettftext() function to create a custom captcha script.

I have ran and tested the code successfully on my PC, running PHP (Version 5.3.8) but when I upload to my shared hosting account running PHP (Version 5.2.17) it comes up with the following error

```
Warning: imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: Could not find/open font in /home/pheelco/public_html/captcha.php on line 17
```

This is line 17;

```
imagettftext($img, 25, 0, 0, 25, $text, "fonts/alger.ttf", $num);
```

I definitely have the folder "fonts" uploaded with that font, its in the public_html folder.

Any ideas?

Note: I don't have access to change any PHP configurations, as I'm using a shared hosting account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It turned out the file name was "alger.TTF" with a capitalised file extension and in my code I was referring to it with a lower-case extension. For some reason this still worked in PHP 5.3.8 but not in PHP 5.2.17 I hope this helps anybody else that comes across this issue

Answer (score 4):

The `imagettftext` documentation says:

> `fontfile`
>
> The path to the TrueType font you wish to use.
>
> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when
>   fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to
>   the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename
>   along a library-defined font path.
>
> When using versions of the GD library lower than 2.0.18, a space
>   character, rather than a semicolon, was used as the 'path separator'
>   for different font files. Unintentional use of this feature will
>   result in the warning message: Warning: Could not find/open font. For
>   these affected versions, the only solution is moving the font to a
>   path which does not contain spaces.
>
> In many cases where a font resides in the same directory as the script
>   using it the following trick will alleviate any include problems.
>
> ```
> <?php // Set the enviroment variable for GD
> putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
>
> // Name the font to be used (note the lack of the .ttf extension)
> $font = 'SomeFont'; ?>
> ```

Did you try this? You can use [`gd_info`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gd-info.php) to check which version of GD you are working with.

Comment: It's not in the same folder though, it's in a sub-directory.

Comment: @MichaelRuta: Then compensate: `putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.') . '/fonts')`

Comment: Solved.

It turned out the file name was "alger.TTF" with a capitalised file extension and in my code I was referring to it with a lower-case extension.

For some reason this still worked in PHP 5.3.8 but not in PHP 5.2.17

I hope this helps anybody else that comes across this issue.