# PHP imaging shows up the question mark

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm testing around with image function but it ends up the question mark on the browser. 
Do you know how to fix this?
I use safari as my browser.

```
<?php

$image = imagecreate(350,70);

$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

putenv("DGFONTPATH=".realpath('.'));

imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 10, 40, $black, 'arial.ttf', "Courier TrueType");

header("Content-Type:image/png");
imagepng($image);




?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. Replace:

```
putenv("DGFONTPATH=".realpath('.'));
```

with:

```
putenv("GDFONTPATH=".realpath('.'));
        ^^
```

Comment: @Toshi Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866743/imagettftext-cannot-find-font-location