# What is the php GD library-defined font path?

Tags: php, gd

The following code does not work on my xampp system:

```
imagettfbbox($fontSize,$angle,"Vera",$txt);
```

The error is:

```
Warning: imagettfbbox(): Invalid font filename
```

The following code does not work, either:

```
imagettfbbox($fontSize,$angle,"Vera.ttf",$txt);
```

But the following code works.

```
imagettfbbox($fontSize,$angle,"C:\\xampp\\php\\extras\\fonts\\ttf\\Vera.ttf",$txt);
```

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php,

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when
> fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to
> the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename
> along a library-defined font path.

So, how to know the GD library-defined font path? I used gd_info(), but it does not show the GD font path.

Comment: Just a bit lower, in the manual, it shows this bit of code: 
`putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));`, this sets the environment variable for GD. Perhaps that's what you're looking for? There's also [getenv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware But if I do not set the environment variable, it should have a default path to search, right?

Comment: I agree that that's what the manual says, but if I do `getenv('GDFONTPATH')`, AlmaLinux 8.5 & PHP 7.4.27, I get nothing. Not finding anything else useful, apart from [other people asking the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866743/imagettftext-cannot-find-font-location).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, I also get nothing for that environment variable on my xampp. Perhaps, it is a GD bug.